# Deploying a self contained React application with Nuget

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I am trying to deploy my .net React JS application on another server on Visual Studio 2019 as a self contained package and this is almost working, except for the Nuget dlls which, although present in the deployed files, are supposed to be found on $(USERPROFILE)/.nuget/packages. But this folder is not present on the 
prod server. My web.config contains this line to start the web site on IIS:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" />
```

So the basic VSIISExeLauncher.exe behavior is to get NuGet file from my initial path $(USERPROFILE)/.nuget/packages. Can I change that ? I was thinking about using "additionalProbingPaths": ["~/***/packages"] in the runtimeconfig.json

Is there any solution to avoid that, or if it is impossible, can I tweak the *.csproj file in order to choose the packages folder ?

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I needed to modify my [ProjectName].runtimeconfig.json and update       "additionalProbingPaths" in the "RuntimeOptions" section

Comment: Did you use the React.js ASP.NET Core template or was it on your own? 'cause I'm having hard time deploying it as a Windows Service

Comment: Well I used the template, but there are so many ways of doing, so many "starter kits" that this is quite difficult to tackle. For big and professional project, my colleagues use Angular. I will consider moving to it.